# android.media.audiofx.Visualizer throwing exception every other time

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper, illegalstateexception, visualizer

I'm making a Live Wallpaper for Android 2.3.3 and it used the Visualizer class.  I've already got a working version of my Visualizer program working as a stand alone but when I place the code into a Live Wallpaper service, my problem begins.  The following code is where the error exists:

```
// Called in my Engine extension's constructor
public void setupVisualizer()
{
    mBytes = null;
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(0);

    // EDIT
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(false); // This fixes the issue
    // END EDIT

    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(
        Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]); // IllegalStateException Thrown

    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener() {
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
            byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                updateVisualizer(bytes);
            }
        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
            bytes[] bytes, int samplingRate) {}
        }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);

    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Here's the weird part, when I'm looking through the live wallpaper list, I'll tap it to view the preview and it works fine.  Without setting it as the active wallpaper, I hit the back button and then select it again and it crashes.  I can repeat this process and it only crashes every other time and works the other times.  If I choose to set it as the active wallpaper, it crashes every time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looking [at the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.java), it seems like `IllegalStateException` is thrown if the state is not `STATE_INITIALIZED`.

Since the constructor sets the state to `STATE_ENABLED` or `STATE_INITIALIZED`, it means that the state when you get the exception is `STATE_ENABLED` (the only option).

In the documentation of `setCaptureSize()` they mention that you should not call this method while the state is `STATE_ENABLED`, so I think you need to call `setEnabled(false)` on the Visualizer object before calling `setCaptureSize()`

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much.  It says I can't award the bounty for another 6 hours but I will once I can.

Comment: I'm glad to hear. I have never worked with Visualizer before, and I hope my method of finding the issue will serve you in other times of need.

Comment: This helped me to fix a similar error I was having with screen orientation! Great job thanks.

Comment: Been looking for this answer a couple of days now, THANK YOU!