# how to retain mediaplayer object in orintation change

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to save media-player object when orientation changes from portrait to landscape mode.
As i know when you change your orientation your activity get recreated so thats why my old media player object get distroyed.i tried onretainNonConfigureInstance method but it wont work for me.

I want old media player object in landscape view to display felixpalmer android-visualizer. To display Visualiser you need to link media player object with visualiser-view.
IS there any alternative way to pass old media player object to landscape view and vice versa??

Comment: With the Attribute `onConfigChanges:orientation` in the Manifest (inside the Activity) you can prevent the recreating. Maybe this is a suitable solution for you.

Comment: @Thommy if i use configchanges in manifest than it will show portetrait xml in landscape view...it should display the xml which is in folder "layout-land" but it display default layout xml when you switch to landscape mode...why this is happening

Comment: Then you need to override the Method `onConfigurationChanged` in your Activity to set the Layout manually.

Comment: I override it but when i override it my program start from configurationchanged method.. not from oncreate

Comment: I got setcapturesize() called in wrong state error..while setting up visualiser .. how to solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could just keep your media player object in a static variable inside the activity so it'll be preserved on orientation changes.

Even though I've never used the *Android Visualizer* component, checking the source code of its [`VisualizerView`](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/blob/master/src/com/pheelicks/visualizer/VisualizerView.java) class I see that it uses the Android's [`Visualizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) class.

As you can see in the documentation of the [`setCaptureSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#setCaptureSize%28int%29) method, it cannot be called while the `Visualizer` is enabled.

This is what I would try to do for your usage pattern:

**Option 1**

Call the `release()` method of the [`VisualizerView`](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/blob/master/src/com/pheelicks/visualizer/VisualizerView.java) class when the screen orientation changes because that will call also the [`release()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#release%28%29) method of the Android's `Visualizer` object thus releasing all the resources and allowing you to create a new one with a call to `link()` on the [`VisualizerView`](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/blob/master/src/com/pheelicks/visualizer/VisualizerView.java) object to link your media player again.

**Option 2**

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222219/android-media-audiofx-visualizer-throwing-exception-every-other-time) question and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9279496/1429331). You could try to modify the source code of the [`VisualizerView`](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/blob/master/src/com/pheelicks/visualizer/VisualizerView.java) class and insert `mVisualizer.setEnabled(false)` inside the `link()` method right after the creation of a new `Visualizer` instance and before the `setCaptureSize` call.

Comment: got setcapturesize() called in wrong state error..while setting up visualiser .. how to solve this error

Comment: @swapniladsure I've edited my answer giving you two different options to try to solve the `setCaptureSize()` error. Try to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add this code in your `manifest.xml`.it will clear your issue

```
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: if i use configchanges in manifest than it will show portetrait xml in landscape view...it should display the xml which is in folder "layout-land" but it display default layout xml when you switch to landscape mode...why this is happening

Comment: got setcapturesize() called in wrong state error..while setting up visualiser .. how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is implementing `OnRetainNonRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and returning your instance of `MediaPlayer`. Then, during `onCreate()` or `onStart()`, call `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` and cast its result to your MediaPlayer variable.

However, this method is deprecated and, in accord to the current documentation, you should encapsulate your logical block in a `Fragment` and use the method `mFragment.setRetainInstance(true)`, so that the fragment will not be recreated with its parent activity.

A Third option would be to use a `Service` to encapsulate the `MediaPlayer`. It will not be recreated with the activity, it will not stop playing as it is independent of the current activity.

Comment: I got " setCaptureSize() called in wrong state error" When i am trying to link my visualiser and mediaplayer instance in landscape mode..but if i create new mediaplayer object and than called visualiser.link(player-object) method than it works good But problem is i have to create new media player object.. 
So now i will try your solution to use fragments..in fragments can i have portrate and landscape fragment on single view?? do u have any example of setretainInstance and getlastNonConfigurationInstance()
im using https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer in my app

Answer (score 0):

You can set the retainInstance property of the fragment that hosts your Media Player to true.
All you need to do is add the following line to your fragments onCreate method:
setRetainInstance(true);